# Powershell stops working with C# class when it contains a method signature with DateTime dt = default

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

We have a Powershell API which exposes a C# class to the powershell user. The user can then call methods on the class. Someone has changed the signature of one of the methods in the class to contain 'DateTime dt = default'. Now if you try and call any methods on the class such as $session.GetVersion() you get the following exception:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "GetVersion": "Encountered an invalid type for a default value."
At F:\Projects\powershell scripts\parameters.ps1:13 char:1
+ $session.GetVersion()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

We have unfortunately released the code like this. I am wondering if there is any workaround we could get users to do with the powershell to get this to wok. Is there any way to get powershell to ignore the method with the signature it does not like, or to get powershell not to have a problem with the use of default ?

I am trying to find a workaround to the problem.

Comment: Change to DateTime dt = New-Object -TypeName DateTime

Comment: @jdweng I think op means they used the `default` keyword in the C# definition of the types in question. Adding PowerShell code to the class definition won't help :)

Comment: Why not send your users an update (an updated C# class)? I am not aware of any way to change the behavior of PS like that, but even if there would be one like that i would be quite wary about possible unexpected side-effects such a changing of PS behavior might come with...

Comment: No, you're boned. The exception occurs as soon as the type has to be reflected on for its members; it doesn't even matter if the method is used. This is arguably a bug in PowerShell; I see no reason to refuse processing of a class the runtime accepts as valid, whether or not PowerShell chooses to support the default value. The (excessively lame) workaround would be to use `Add-Type` to set up a wrapper that removes or wraps the offending member, exposing an overload without a default; calling this method from C# is of course no problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Very interesting. You should add this as an answer. It would be good to have a reproducible example. If this is really a powershell bug, this might become a very useful post.

Comment: Attempting to repro this in PowerShell 7.3.1 on Linux fails, so it's likely already fixed in some form or another. I can't be bothered to look up the diff; a search for the issue in the [repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) gives way too many results.

Comment: We are patching as didn't want to ask customers to upgrade powershell. Thanks for all your answers!